# Descriptive text for figure depending on location

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I often find myself writing `see Figure~\ref{fig:figname}, below` or `see Figure~\ref{fig:figname}, above`, or similar phrases.

Is there a way to make LaTeX automatically decide between "above" and "below" depending on the location where the figure is rendered?

Comment: varioref package

Comment: Even simpler: the `cleveref` package: it will suffice to type `see \Cref{fig:figurename}` to obtain `see Figure above` (or below, or nextpage or previous page).

Comment: @Bernard Are you sure? As far as I recall, `cleveref` only records the kind of object, but not its location, so `\Cref{fig:figurename}` will only give `Figure #`. On the other hand, as David suggested, `varioref` adds a location-associated string.

Comment: Chcek out http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187105/references-to-floats-without-ever-using-figure-numbers-possbily-using-lua-or-py/187359#187359  I am really proud of this one!

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina/ I wrote too hastily: actually, `cleveref` more or less cooperates with `varioref` and is customisable enough to allow defining personal formatting of cross references so as to obtain both the reference type and its location. I did something like that some years ago (but don't remember the exact context).