# How to make a test on the current page number?

Tags: labels

How could I test whether some label is on the current page, or on the previous or next one. Typically I would like to build a macro `\onthispage{label}{text1}{text2}` which would print `text1` if the page and the text are on the same page and `text2` otherwise. This could be useful when one wants to insert something like this into the TeX source:

> see the figure \ref{figure}\onthispage{figure}{above}{page \pageref{figure}}.

An extension would be to have this kind of command to compare the current page to `\pageref{label}` and print `this page`, `previous page`,  `next page` or `page \pageref{label}` accordingly.

I've tried a dirty trick with a definition of a extra label inside the command `\onthispage` but this fails. Any ideas ?

Comment: You know package `varioref`?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek. Not yet ! I'll have a look at it tonight. Thanks !

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187105/references-to-floats-without-ever-using-figure-numbers-possbily-using-lua-or-py/187359#187359