# Reference a figure (float) with respect to its relative position (the figure below, etc.)

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

Is there a way to reference a figure such that the output produced is something like:

"Please refer to the figure below."

?

I imagine the relevant code fragment would look something like

```
\begin{figure} \label{figure-one}
    <figure code>
\end{figure}
It is easier to understand if one refers to the figure \figurelocation{figure-one}.
```

where `\figurelocation` produces above, below, on the previous page, etc. as required.

Since the position of floats can change as text is introduced, it would be nice to have such a functionality, instead of writing verbatim `the figure above` etc. Furthermore, this might be preferable if the figure is referred to multiple times in a section, in which case it's probably stylistically better to write `the figure above` etc. from time to time than continuously writing `Figure 1` again and again.

A cursory search on this forum showed that this question had not been asked before (perhaps I didn't find it).

Comment: Have you had a look to the `varioref` package?

Comment: No I have not! Although, it seems to have the command `\vpageref`which comes close...

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187105/references-to-floats-without-ever-using-figure-numbers-possbily-using-lua-or-py/187359?s=5|0.0260#187359